How to find a reccurence formula like Newton's identity for $\sum_{i<j} x_i^m x_j^m$?
In the question below the $e_i$ correspond to the elementary symmetric polynomials.
Using the Mathematica function FindLinearReccurence I found that
$$
q_m = x_1^m x_2^m + x_2^m x_3^m + x_1^m x_3^m = e_2q_{m-1}-e_3e_1q_{m-2}+e_3^2q_{m-3}.
$$
That 3 term reccurence looks similar to the Newton identity for $x_1^m+x_2^m+x_3^m$. If we set $p_m=x_1^m+x_2^m+x_3^m$, $q_m$ can be expressed as $\frac{p_m^2-p_{2m}}{2}$ but using that seems to either lead to a lot of computations or it does not help.
My questions are:

Is there an elegant proof for the reccurence formula of $q_m$ ? By elegant I mean a proof that does not require a lot of algebraic manipulations like multiplications, powers of polynomials and/or additions in order to find the previous reccurence formula.

I am less interested in the following but is there a proof that would find a reccurence formula in the case of $n$ variables ?



Hint for both parts: Consider the cubic with roots $1/x$. You're interested in $q_m = (x_1x_2x_3)^m ( 1/x_1^m + 1/x_2^m + 1/x_3^m)$. Unsurprisingly, we have another Newton identity, but just need to figure out the coefficients.

@CalvinLin Thank you for the hint :). I realized after using your hint that I could also just consider applying Newton's identity directly to $y_i=x_1x_2x_3/x_i$ and use for the second term in Newton's identity $x_1x_2x_3/(x_ix_j)=x_k$ with $k$ the element of the complement of ${x_i,x_j}$ in ${x_1,x_2,x_3}$. For the generalization I suppose that you were thinking of $\sum_{i_1<i_2<...<i_{n-1}}x_{i_1}^mx_{i_2}^mx_{i_3}^m....x_{i_{n-1}}^m$ rather than $\sum_{i<j}x_{i}^mx_{j}^m$. Maybe there is no reccurence formula for $\sum_{i<j}x_{i}^mx_{j}^m$ when there is more than 3 variables.
